# How to show only the Check-boxes that have been marked in react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Web Page Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfiTk.png)

So i have like combination of input field and check boxes being rendered here by pressing enter key in the top Input field.

How do I like when press "Completed" in the bottom button then show only those generated input fields that have been marked in their check boxes.

Main Component :

```
import React from "react";
import {Add, Bottom} from "../index";

const CardMain = () => (

    <div class="row ">
        <div class = "col col-lg-6 mx-auto mt-5 card">
           <div class = "card-title">
                <h2 class="text-center">THINGS TO DO</h2>



           </div>
            <Add/>

    </div>
    </div>

);

export default CardMain;
```

The component that adds input fields

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Bottom from "./Bottom";
const Add = () => {
    const [length,setLength] = useState(0);
    const [count,setCount] = useState([]);
    const[input,setInput] = useState("");
    const InputChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    }

    const Remove = (value) => {
        const list = [...count];
        list.splice(value,1);
        setCount(list);
    }

    const handle = (event) => {
        if(event.charCode === 13){
            setLength(length+1);
           setCount([...count,input]);
           setInput("");
        }
    }
    return (
        <>

            <input type="text" id="bar" className="form-control" value={input} onKeyPress={
                handle} onChange={InputChange}
                   placeholder="Add New "/>
            {count.map((value) =>
                length !== 0 ? (
                    <div className="input-group mb-3 mt-2">
                        <div className="input-group-text">
                            <input className="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox"/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={value}
                        />
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick = {Remove}>
                            X
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ) : null
            )

            }
            <Bottom/>
        </>

    );

}

export default Add;
```

The component that I need help in :

```
import React from "react";

const Bottom = () => {






    return(
        <div class="row mt-4 mb-0 bg-light">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col border-start">

            <p class="text-nowrap">Things to do</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn">
                All
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn">
                Active
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn">
                Completed
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

 );
}

export default Bottom;
```

I tried a bunch but I have no clue how to do this